# Как всегда держать актуальную версию сайта и базы данных у себя на компьютере?

Tags: wordpress, база-данных, администрирование, веб-сайт

Существует сайт на wordpress с регулярно пополняемой базой данных, сайт разрастается и уже файлы сайта весят более 1 Gb, а размер БД более 330 Mb.

Раньше, когда сайт был меньше, я с помощью бесплатной версии Duplicator обходился: делал новый пакет время от времени.

Сейчас бесплатная версия Duplicator не позволяет делать пакет с таким размером, а на платную подписку без ограничений пакета нет средств. Я могу довольствоваться только снимком БД, а хотелось бы иметь актуальный снимок сайта на сегодняшний день у себя на пк.

Пару лет назад я пользовался FTP-клиентом Filezilla для работы с файлами сайта на сервере, но такой подход мне не нравился, но я допускаю, что такой подход может иметь место, если кто-то обоснует его целесообразность.

И если я сейчас хочу создать актуальный снимок сайта мне нужно заходить на хостинг, формировать архив с файлами сайта, скачивать дамп БД с помощью хостинга или Duplicator. Это неудобно и долго.

Вопрос: хотелось бы найти удобный способ всегда держать актуальную версию сайта и базы данных у себя на компьютере. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что посмотреть, почитать по этой теме?

Comment: Если сервер полностью под вашим контролем, а не какой нибудь обычный хостинг и вы можете на нем запускать произвольные сервисы я бы предложил rsync. Только фаерволом его порт прикрыть для надежности, что бы только с вашей машины доступ был

Comment: Не, rsync лучше дёргать через логин-пасс от ssh. Тогда и логин-пасс будут передаваться в шифрованном виде и сами файлы. Ванильная версия протокола тягает всё в открытом виде. Это хорошо для локалки, но не очень для интернета, особенно, если снапы БД.

Comment: Есть автоматическое решение от [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/). БД хорошо синхронизирует [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/ru/products/navicat-for-mysql). Ну а бакапы файлов с дедупликацией можно делать [Borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Если над сайтом работает несколько человек, можно поднять сервер управления версиями наподобие [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/)